# Materialize class row with unequal height

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm Using Materialize http://materializecss.com/grid.html 
The problem is when my card can have different sizes and it seems that materialize grid doesn't support that. Here is the exact problem.
[image]
Is there any way I can make it more responsive and remove that extra space?
Any reference would do.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by using this repository http://masonry.desandro.com/